Create path from points and colour the line according a field in the point shape
I've got a shapefile with points with several fields (coordinates, datetime, speed). I want to create a path for them by the datetime and colour each line between vertex (which they are the points) according the field speed. For example if one point has as speed 30 and the next has speed 50, colour the line as a colour ramp (for example each 10km/h). At the moment I could create the path (but without any information regarding its vertex), and I do not know how can I colour each line between vertex. Is it possible?
